# offset time (time with time zone) in jdbc PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, java-time

I am trying to save and retrieve `java.time.OffsetTime` into PostgreSQL version 10.5, JDBC driver latest (v 42.2.5).

The Offset time is saved but with an invalid offset (it takes app server offset instead of the passed offset).

According to: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html `TIME WITH TIMEZONE` is not supported (yet?).

> Note that ZonedDateTime, Instant and OffsetTime / TIME [ WITHOUT
>   TIMEZONE ] are not supported

My question, is I want to save offset time into Postgres, so what are alternatives?

**Note**, I only care about time (it is actually a timetable) but I need to know the offset as well for comparing reasons with current_time.

My Example:

```
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "time with time zone")
    private OffsetTime serviceTime;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "timestamp with time zone")
    private OffsetDateTime serviceDateTime;

    private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();
}
```

The main:

```
{
        OffsetTime serviceTime = OffsetTime.parse("10:00+02:00");
        OffsetDateTime serviceDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now().with(serviceTime);
        System.out.println(serviceTime);
        System.out.println(serviceDateTime);

        Customer customer = new Customer().withName("wael")
                .withServiceTime(serviceTime)
                .withServiceDateTime(serviceDateTime);
        System.out.println("customer: " +  customer);
        customerRepository.save(customer);
    }

    {
        Customer dbCustomer = customerRepository.findById(1L).get();

        OffsetTime dbServiceTime = dbCustomer.getServiceTime();
        OffsetDateTime dbServiceDateTime = dbCustomer.getServiceDateTime();

        System.out.println(dbServiceTime);
        System.out.println(dbServiceDateTime);
        System.out.println("from db customer: " +  dbCustomer);
    }
```

Database:

```
id  created_date    name    service_date_time   service_time
1   2018-10-15 10:38:27.814000  wael    2018-10-15 08:00:00.000000  10:00:00 +03:00
```

Output:

```
10:00+02:00
2018-10-15T10:00+02:00
customer: Customer(id=null, name=wael, serviceTime=10:00+02:00, serviceDateTime=2018-10-15T10:00+02:00, createdDate=2018-10-15T07:10:59.900Z)
10:00+03:00
2018-10-15T11:00+03:00
from db customer: Customer(id=1, name=wael, serviceTime=10:00+03:00, serviceDateTime=2018-10-15T11:00+03:00, createdDate=2018-10-15T07:10:59.900Z)
```

Note, my machine timezone is +3 (hence the printed information from db is +3), and my database server is a docker image with `UTC` datetime settings.

Observations:

The OffsetDatetime is saved correctly (as UTC) and retrieved correctly.
The **OffsetTime** is saved **incorrect** (it should be `10:00:00 +02:00` or `11:00:00 +03:00` or even `08:00:00 +00:00` not `10:00:00 +03:00`, and retrieved incorrect!)

Comment: Did you read [comment in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) regarding `time with time zone`? "*The type time with time zone is defined by the SQL standard, but the definition exhibits properties which lead to **questionable usefulness*" - maybe a simple `time` column together with an `offset` column that stores the offset in minutes is a better choice.

Comment: Beware that an offset is not the same as a time zone. `+02:00` is an offset from UTC. `Europe/Paris` is a time zone (that happens to be at offset `+02:00` as I type, but isn’t all year and has not always been in summer either). If what you really need is an offset, would it work just to convert your time to UTC? If what you need is a time zone, I think the best is to define a `varchar` column for the time zone ID.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, correct, this is because of DST rules. I think Postgres uses the notion of timezone to express about Offset.

Answer (score 0):

With JPA 2.2, you can also use OffsetTime in Postgresql.

```
@Column(name = "offset_time", columnDefinition = "TIME WITH TIME ZONE")
private OffsetTime offsetTime;
```

That's how it is stored in my database: 22:00:00.000000 +02:00